# gradle archiva integration copy jar from build to archiva repository

Tags: gradle, archiva

I am integrating gradle to archiva.I was able to build the jar of the project successfully , but craeting inside build/libs.

I want to add this jar to my archiva repository internal after build. please guide me

```
my archiva repo
http://localhost:8080/repository/internal/
```

Answer (score 2):

See Gradle docs:
[Chapter 34. Maven Publishing](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html) - describes how to use 'maven-publish' gradle plugin to define publications and repositories.
34.4. Performing a publish - contains full example of additions to **build.gradle**:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

group = 'org.gradle.sample'
version = '1.0'

publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
        }
    }
}
publishing {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "http://localhost:8080/repository/internal/"
            credentials {
                username repoUser
                password repoPassword
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Add credentials {} section if you need to supply username/password for repository. repoUser and repoPassword are variables defined somewhere else. For example, apply [gradle-properties-plugin](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/net.saliman.properties) and define these variables in **gradle-local.properties**:

```
repoUser=jsmith
repoPassword=secret
```

Make sure not to commit this file into source code repository.